# A verb meaning make (a climate) mild

Tags: word-request

There is this sentence in which I'm trying to count a number of effects that restoring a currenly dried out lake can have on a particular region. I want to say that after reviving the lake the microclimate in that region will be affected so in winters and summers it wouldn't be that cold or hot because the lake makes the climate there mild:

> Restoring Lake X can [the verb] the surroundings climate.

The verb I need means *make mild* then. Any suggestions?

Comment: Or you could say "...make the local microclimate more temperate" instead of looking for a verb.

Comment: Restoring Lake X would make the climate around it milder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

People often say lakes and other large bodies of water **moderate** the weather.  In that usage, moderate means [*to lessen the intensity or extremeness of* - M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moderate).

Here is an article describing the phenomenon in the question: http://www.waterencyclopedia.com/Ce-Cr/Climate-Moderator-Water-as-a.html

Comment: That sounds to me like impact as a verb. To moderate one's drinking or food intake, but moderate the climate?? Sounds odd to my ear.

Comment: @Lambie, they didn't invent the word just for drinking and eating.  :-)  I spent many years on the Great Lakes, and applying it to weather was common usage.

Comment: In English, I don't believe one can say semantically correctly: moderate the weather. Moderate as a verb does not mean that in English.

Comment: @Lambie, did you see the M-W citation?  I'm wondering if it just sounds odd to you because you've never had occasion to hear it applied to weather.  Here's a scientific article on water as a climate moderator: http://www.waterencyclopedia.com/Ce-Cr/Climate-Moderator-Water-as-a.html

Comment: I didn't see that article but water can be a climate moderatOR, it just can't moderate climate. In English, it is not a verb in that sense. I do see that that article uses it like that. Not sure I would.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the transitive verb **temper**, which can mean "to dilute, qualify, or soften by the addition or influence of something else" (source: [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/temper)) or "to moderate or mitigate; to soften or tone down" (source: [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/temper)).

As **temper** is related to the adjective **temperate**, which is frequently used in discussions of climate, it seems appropriate here.

> Restoring Lake X can temper the surrounding climate.